# Finiteness of the class number and Dirichlet's Units Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Why do these two results do not extend to an arbitrary Dedekind Domain? For instance, I know two ways to prove the finiteness of the class number: by means of the pigeonhole principle and by means of the geometric methods due to Minkowski. But why these arguments fail in an arbitrary Dedekind Domain?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking for more than just the statement which determines the rank of of the units of any order in a number field $K$. Also, have you thought PIDs? For example $k[[x]]$ has units which are those power series with constant term nonzero. As far as I can tell, this does not have a finite rank free part.

Comment: Also for class numbers, if I recall correctly the ideal class group is the same as the divisor class group if the Dedekind domain is the coordinate ring of a nonsingular integral curve. In which case, I think an elliptic curve shows you that finiteness cannot hold.

Comment: thanks for your answers, dude! they were really helpful!

Comment: Unless you append "@K02" to the start, I think K02 will not get a message that you commented on those comments.

Comment: @KCd Surprisingly, it seems like I do get the message! Just learned a new thing about this site haha

Comment: @K02  Amazing.  Maybe when there is only one commenter that person gets notified...

Answer (score 2):

They don't extend simply because you can find counterexamples: $\mathbf C[x,y]/(y^2 - (x^3-x))$ is Dedekind with ideal class group $\mathbf C/\mathbf Z[i]$ and the unit group of $K[x]$ is $K^\times$, so $K[x]$ has an infinite unit group when $K$ is an infinite field.

Turning your question around, we can ask "why" those two finiteness  results in algebraic number theory. It can be tied ultimately to the finiteness of $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z$, which by the Chinese remainder theorem and an induction argument is due to the finiteness of $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ for prime $p$. (When $A$ is a Dedekind domain, all of its residue rings $A/\mathfrak a$ for nonzero ideals are finite if and only if its residue fields $A/\mathfrak p$ are finite when $\mathfrak p$ runs over the nonzero prime ideals in $A$.) When $k$ is a *finite* field, $k[x]$ has finite residue rings $k[x]/(f)$ whenever $f$ is nonzero and you get analgoues of the finiteness results you mention when working with integral extensions of $k[x]$.

A fancier point of view: when $K$ is a number field, the finiteness of the class group of $K$ and the unit theorem for $\mathcal O_K^\times$ are, taken *together* equivalent to the compactness of the idelic group $J_K^1/K^\times$. And that ultimately (but not entirely) is related to local compactness of the completions of a number field, which is due to local compactness of the completions of $\mathbf Q$ (namely $\mathbf R$ and all the $\mathbf Q_p$'s). A non-archimedean complete valued field is locally compact if and only if its value group is discrete and its residue field is finite. The residue field associated to a non-archimedean absolute value on a field is unchanged under completion of the field for that absolute value, so the local compactness of $\mathbf Q_p$ is tied to the finiteness of the residue field of $\mathbf Q_p$, which "uncompleting" back to $\mathbf Q$ returns us to the property that the residue fields $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ for prime $p$ are all finite.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer!!